# Spin image infinitely

Tags: jquery, html, css, transform

I have a image like an old telephone circular dial. It has 8 small circles inside it. I want to rotate it 45degrees and then stop for a while and then rotate to the next element (more 45degrees)... This should continue infinitely and the dial should keep on rotating. I have used css for rotation and jquery for triggering the event. The problem is that is to rotate it for infinite time.

CSS

```
.ghoomna1{

-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;z-index: 100;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1) rotate(45deg) ;

}
.ghoomna2{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;z-index: 100;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1) rotate(90deg) ;
}
.ghoomna3{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;z-index: 100;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1) rotate(135deg) ;
}
.ghoomna4{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;z-index: 100;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1) rotate(180deg) ;
}
.ghoomna5{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;z-index: 100;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1) rotate(225deg) ;
}
.ghoomna6{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;z-index: 100;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1) rotate(270deg) ;
}
.ghoomna7{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;z-index: 100;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1) rotate(315deg) ;
}
.ghoomna8{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;z-index: 100;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1) rotate(360deg) ;
}
```

JQUERY

```
(function( `$` ){
`$`.fn.myfunction = function() {
    `$`("#dial").addClass("ghoomna1").delay(500).queue(function(next){
    `$`("#dial").removeClass("ghoomna1").addClass("ghoomna2").delay(500).queue(function(next){
    `$`("#dial").removeClass("ghoomna2").addClass("ghoomna3").delay(500).queue(function(next){
    `$`("#dial").removeClass("ghoomna3").addClass("ghoomna4").delay(500).queue(function(next){
    `$`("#dial").removeClass("ghoomna4").addClass("ghoomna5").delay(500).queue(function(next){
    `$`("#dial").removeClass("ghoomna5").addClass("ghoomna6").delay(500).queue(function(next){
    `$`("#dial").removeClass("ghoomna6").addClass("ghoomna7").delay(500).queue(function(next){
    `$`("#dial").addClass("ghoomna8");
    next();
    });
    next();
});
    next();
});
    next();
});
    next();
});
    next();
});
    next();
    });
};
}( jQuery ));
$('#dial').myfunction();
```

Comment: If you don't mind using a plugin I recommend you to use :
http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/
It's an easy way to deal with time, in your case you could use repeat().

Comment: Why not use a CSS animation? You can set the animation to run infinitely.

Comment: seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144390/css3-infinite-spin?rq=1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Rm3K/

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/sa5ZF/

I can't tell much about your page with the code you've posted but here's how to rotate images infinitely using CSS:

**HTML**

```
<img class="rotate" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Cog_font_awesome.svg/512px-Cog_font_awesome.svg.png" />
```

**CSS**

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
            animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-ms-transform: rotate(359deg);}

    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
```

You are using multiple `id`'s but all the CSS is the same so I'm suggest adding a common class to your elements that you want to rotate.

Also, with jQuery you can start and stop the rotation at any time by calling

```
$('.rotate').removeClass('rotate');
$('.rotate').addClass('rotate');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CSS `animation` as opposed to `transition`, which features an `infinite` keyword for repeating:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations#Making_it_repeat